# Mock not found in the registry for Camel route test

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to test a Camel route (polling messages from an SQS queue) containing

```
.bean("messageParserProcessor")
```

where `messageParserProcessor` is a Processor.
The test:

```
public class SomeTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    private final String queueName = ...;
    private final String producerTemplateUri = "aws-sqs://" + queueName + ...;

    private static final String MESSAGE_PARSER_PROCESSOR_MOCK_ENDPOINT = "mock:messageParserProcessor";

    @EndpointInject(uri = MESSAGE_PARSER_PROCESSOR_MOCK_ENDPOINT)
    protected MockEndpoint messageParserProcessor;

    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }

    @Before
    public void setUpContext() throws Exception {
        context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                interceptSendToEndpoint("bean:messageParserProcessor")
                    .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                    .process(MESSAGE_PARSER_PROCESSOR_MOCK_ENDPOINT);
            }
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void testParser() throws Exception {
        context.start();
        String expectedBody = "test";

        messageParserProcessor.expectedBodiesReceived(expectedBody);

        ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
        template.sendBody(producerTemplateUri, expectedBody);

        messageParserProcessor.assertIsSatisfied();
        context.stop();
    }
}
```

When I run the test I get this error:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException:
Failed to create route route1 at:
>>> InterceptSendToEndpoint[bean:messageParserProcessor -> [process[ref:mock:messageParserProcessor]]] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[aws-sqs://xxx... 
because of No bean could be found in the registry for: mock:messageParserProcessor of type: org.apache.camel.Processor
```

Same error if I replace `interceptSendToEndpoint(...)` with `mockEndpointsAndSkip("bean:messageParserProcessor")`

The test can be executed (but obviously doesn't pass) when I don't use a mock:

```
interceptSendToEndpoint("bean:messageParserProcessor")
    .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {}
     });
```

So the problem is the mock that is not found, what is wrong in the way I create it?

Comment: Try: interceptSendToEndpoint("messageParserProcessor") i.e. with no .bean inside.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti same error. Again, the problem is that the mock is not found in the registry, I don't understand why...

Answer (score 0):

So I found a workaround to retrieve mocks from the registry:

```
interceptSendToEndpoint("bean:messageParserProcessor")
    .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
    .bean(getMockEndpoint(MESSAGE_PARSER_PROCESSOR_MOCK_ENDPOINT));
    // Instead of
    // .process(MESSAGE_PARSER_PROCESSOR_MOCK_ENDPOINT);
```

But I still don't understand why using `.process("mock:someBean")` doesn't work...

Comment: By the way, you don't need to use .process. You can use .to(...) if it is defined as an endpoint or .bean.